# Split each element by bracket in variable and find occurrence

Tags: python, text, matplotlib, find-occurrences

I have a text file which has arrays appended to them[image: 'image']
What I want to do is extract it from the text file and work out how many times `index[2]` occurs for each word in the text file. For instance hablar occurs once etc. I will then use that to plot a graph.

The problem is that when i import the file it comes as a list within a list

```
with open("wrongWords.txt") as file:
    array1 = []
    array2 = [] 
    for element in file:
        array1.append(element)    
    x=array1[0]
    print(x)
```

Printing x gives me

`(12, 'a', 'hablar', 'to speak')(51, 'a', 'ocurrir', 'to occur/happen')(12, 'a', 'hablar', 'to speak')(2, 'a', 'poder', 'to be able')(11, 'a', 'llamar', 'to call/name')`

Comment: What is the required output?

Comment: I am trying to get it to output something like this.  hablar 2, llamar 1 etc  in order to plot it.

Comment: Updated the answer based on your required login. Hope this is what you want. O/P: {'hablar': 2, 'ocurrir': 1, 'poder': 1, 'llamar': 1}

Comment: Hi Moinuddin Quadri, this is along the lines of what I am looking for. however I need it to do it from the text file

Comment: I believe you already know how to read content from text file :)

Comment: You may refer this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list-with-python

Comment: Since you mentioned in the post: *printing x gives me (12, 'a', 'hablar', 'to speak')(51, 'a', 'ocurrir', 'to occur/happen')(12, 'a', 'hablar', 'to speak')(2, 'a', 'poder', 'to be able')(11, 'a', 'llamar', 'to call/name')*, I thought you already able to read the content from string

Comment: Yes got it to work now, thank you Moinuddin Quadri :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert your `string` into `list`, do:

```
>>> s = "(12, 'a', 'hablar', 'to speak')(51, 'a', 'ocurrir', 'to occur/happen')(12, 'a', 'hablar', 'to speak')(2, 'a', 'poder', 'to be able')(11, 'a', 'llamar', 'to call/name')"
>>> s = s.replace(')(', '),(')
# s = "(12, 'a', 'hablar', 'to speak'),(51, 'a', 'ocurrir', 'to occur/happen'),(12, 'a', 'hablar', 'to speak'),(2, 'a', 'poder', 'to be able'),(11, 'a', 'llamar', 'to call/name')"

>>> my_list = list(eval(s))
# my_list = [(12, 'a', 'hablar', 'to speak'), (51, 'a', 'ocurrir', 'to occur/happen'), (12, 'a', 'hablar', 'to speak'), (2, 'a', 'poder', 'to be able'), (11, 'a', 'llamar', 'to call/name')]
```

To get the count of each `key` (at index 2 in your case) in `list`:

```
>>> my_dict = {}
>>> for item in my_list:
...     my_dict[item[2]] = my_dict.get(item[2], 0) + 1
...
>>> my_dict
{'hablar': 2, 'ocurrir': 1, 'poder': 1, 'llamar': 1}
```